# Generate random table (array of objects) of sport teams standings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, random, html-table

I need to create a table of team standings which values (wins/draws/losses) are randomly generated. The teams in the table are given, and the number of games each team played is a number of teams -1 (every team played with each other).

I have a function that generates a table from an array of objects, so I want to create another function that would take an array with team names and would return an object of arrays.

Example of this. Input array would be:`["Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Manchester Utd", "Liverpool"]`

and result would be (of course each time different but for example):

```
[
{Team: Manchester Utd, Wins:2, Draws:1, Losses:0, Points:7},
{Team: Liverpool, Wins:2, Draws:0, Losses:1, Points:6},
{Team: Chelsea, Wins:1, Draws:1, Losses:1, Points:4},
{Team: Arsenal, Wins:0, Draws:0, Losses:3, Points:0)
]
```

After made into a table:

```
+----------------+------+-------+--------+--------+
|      Team      | Wins | Draws | Losses | Points |
+----------------+------+-------+--------+--------+
| Manchester Utd |    2 |     1 |     0  |      7 |
| Liverpool      |    2 |     0 |     1  |      6 |
| Chelsea        |    1 |     1 |     1  |      4 |
| Arsenal        |    0 |     0 |     3  |      0 |
+----------------+------+-------+--------+--------+
```

I struggle with thinking of the logic that would make it both random and the wins/losses/draws made sense. That means a team has played only the set number of games, overall numbers of wins and losses are same and sometimes there are no draws, sometimes more of them etc.

Any help or nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Hi,
Why don't you iterate the input array to create match. each match can be an object that has 2 teams and their score. then you can reduce the matches to the standings of your "league"

Comment: @dor272 Thank you for comment! That sounds like it should work and may actually help me with another issue that I have to deal with, outside of what is written in the post. Whole time I was  trying to think of some "math" driven approach. I'll give it a try once I have a moment. Thanks!